# Javascript - Sort array of object based on another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object

I have an array of object and will like to sort the properties of each object according to sequence of another array

```
let arrToSort = [
   { Architect: 'Terry', Client: 'AZ', ClientType: 'Kids', Location: 'USA'},
   { Architect: 'Mary', Client: 'XY', ClientType: 'Clothes', Location: 'Germany'},
   { Architect: 'Jerry', Client: 'BC', ClientType: 'Construction', Location: 'Canada'}
];

let accordingTo = ["ClientType", "Architect", "Location", "Client"];
```

Should look like:

```
finalArr = [
   { ClientType: 'Kids', Architect: 'Terry', Location: 'USA', Client: 'AZ'},
   { ClientType: 'Clothes', Architect: 'Mary', Location: 'Germany', Client: 'XY'},
   { ClientType: 'Construction', Architect: 'Jerry', Location: 'Canada', Client: 'BC'}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arrToSort = [{ Architect: 'Terry', Client: 'AZ', ClientType: 'Kids', Location: 'USA' }, { Architect: 'Mary', Client: 'XY', ClientType: 'Clothes', Location: 'Germany' }, { Architect: 'Jerry', Client: 'BC', ClientType: 'Construction', Location: 'Canada' }];
let accordingTo = ["ClientType", "Architect", "Location", "Client"];

let finalArray = arrToSort.map(itm => Object.keys(itm).sort((a, b) => accordingTo.indexOf(a) - accordingTo.indexOf(b)).reduce((tr, key) => {
  tr[key] = itm[key]
  return tr
}, {}))

console.log(finalArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The keys in Map are ordered while keys added to object are not. Thus,
> when iterating over it, a Map object returns keys in order of
> insertion. (Note that in the ECMAScript 2015 spec objects do preserve
> creation order for string and Symbol keys, so traversal of an object
> with ie only string keys would yield keys in order of insertion)

```js
let arrToSort = [{
    Architect: 'Terry',
    Client: 'AZ',
    ClientType: 'Kids',
    Location: 'USA'
  },
  {
    Architect: 'Mary',
    Client: 'XY',
    ClientType: 'Clothes',
    Location: 'Germany'
  },
  {
    Architect: 'Jerry',
    Client: 'BC',
    ClientType: 'Construction',
    Location: 'Canada'
  }
];
let accordingTo = ["ClientType", "Architect", "Location", "Client"];

function sortByKeys(arr, keyOrder) {
  let newArray = [];
  arr.map((obj) => {
    const newObj = {};
    keyOrder.forEach((key) => {
      newObj[key] = obj[key];
    })
    newArray.push(newObj)
    return obj;
  });
  return newArray;
}
arrToSort = sortByKeys(arrToSort, accordingTo);

console.log(arrToSort);
```